# DoctrineMongoDB : How to set annotation in a document to store a specific structure?

Tags: mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm, doctrine-mongodb

I am implementing a php class that must model this :

```
/** @Document */
classMember {

    /** @String */
    protected $fname;

    /** @String */
    protected $lname;

    /** @String */
    protected $email;

    /** @Int */
    protected $cell;

    /** @String */
    protected $password;

    /** @Int */
    protected $gender;

    /** @Int */
    protected $loc = array();

    /** ????? */
    protected $info;
}
```

I want info field to hold this structure in itself :

```
info Object
[
 contact ["phoneNumber1" , "phoneNumber2"] ,
 address ["USA, NY 8791 John St."] ,
 email ["my@domain.com", "me@site.info"]
]
```

Should i implement another info.php class?If not,how can i implement this?
Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$info` may use an [Embed One](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/embedded-mapping.html#embed-one) mapping. The class you embed would then have mappings for the `contact`, `address`, and `email` fields.

If `contact` and `email` are really intended to hold multiple phone numbers and email addresses, respectively, then I would suggest using the [Collection](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#collection) mapping, which is an arbitrary array of unmapped values. Alternatively, these could be [Embed Many](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/embedded-mapping.html#embed-many) relationships to PhoneNumber and Email objects, but that may be unnecessary overhead since it would entail storing an array of single-field (I assume) objects, instead of an array of strings.

I'm not sure why you represented the `address` field as an array of strings, but that would benefit from being an Embed Many relationship of Address objects. Address would then have specific fields (e.g. country, province/state). Allowing the user to enter their address as a single string may be convenient, but it makes data management and validation a nightmare.